# Поиск элемента в векторе

Tags: c++

Нужна функция поиска элемента в векторе. Т.е., например, есть вектор с повторяющимися числами, если есть такое число в векторе, нужно вернуть истину. Может, в стандартной библиотеке есть готовое решение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не поверите, но такая функция есть! И она даже называется загадочно - `find` :).

Читать детальнее с [примерами](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/?kw=find).

Comment: перед чтения примеров хочу спросить. она возращает указатель на позицию вхождения или мусор. мне 0 или 1 надо

Comment: А вот вначале нужно почитать! Там написано, что если что то нашло - возвратит указатель (итератор) на найденное. Если нет - последний элемент (в случае с вектором это обычно `myvector.end()`.

Но может быть Вам нужен [std::cout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/?kw=count).

Comment: Спасибо. Лучше я сам переберу. Но все равно спасибо. Учту ее на будующее, вдруг последний элемент искомое.

Comment: последний элемент не может быть "искомым". Потому что то, что в качестве параметра задается как последний элемент, это "за последним элементом" на самом деле. Поэтому все будет работать правильно.

Ещё раз другими словами. vector.end() указывает на самый конец вектора, за последним элементом вектора. Разыминовать его нельзя.

Можно почитать ещё на [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252002/what-is-the-past-the-end-iterator-in-stl-c) с картинками.

А вот писать ручками - это дело такое. Можно легко натворить ошибок даже в током простом коде.